# Java Regex Substring

Tags: java, regex, string

Hi i have a string and would like to extract a sub-string that matches a regex the code i currently have removes the sub-string i want it to be the only part that should be kept.

What i have, this removes it, i want to keep it:

```
String ticketReference = "You have been assigned to the following Support Ticket: ST-00003 bla bla bla";

ticketReference =  ticketReference.replaceAll("'((ST-)[0-9]{5})", " ");
```

Desired Output : "ST-00003"

Thanx in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use capture groups to do this, they are denoted `$n` in Java:

```
String ticketReference = "You have been assigned to the following Support Ticket: ST-00003 bla bla bla";
ticketReference =  ticketReference.replaceAll("^.*(ST-[0-9]{5}).*$", "$1");
```

Comment: Works Great if There is not a newline after the ST-00003, how do i make it still return correct if there is a newline ? thanks

Comment: no matter got it thaks `code ticketReference.replaceAll("^.*(ST-[0-9]{5}[\\n]*).*$", "$1"); `

Comment: You can make the `.` match `\n` too by setting the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag: `"(?s)^.*(ST-[0-9]{5}).*$"`.

Answer (score 0):

The `replaceAll` solution has **no error handling** so if the match isn't found the string is left unchanged.

---

Here is a proper way to do it using `Pattern` and `Matcher` (and in my mind much easier):

```
String stringToDecode = 
     "You have been assigned to the following Support Ticket: ST-00003 bla bla";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("ST-[0-9]{5}").matcher(stringToDecode);

if (!m.find())
    throw new CouldNotFindTicketException(stringToDecode);

String ticketReference = m.group();
//...
```